# jQuery Regex Question - Simple Match

Tags: jquery, regex

How can I match something using jquery that is set up as such:

- id="intersection_resources_4_5" // hit
- id="intersection_content_6_5" // hit
- id="intersection_content_4_3" // not

I want to do something like:

```
$("div:regex(id, intersection_*_*_5)").each(function(){
    $(this).click();
});
```

Is this doable? Assuming, the * is a wildcard, which I cannot seem to get to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want a plugin, and you don't want to create your own selector filter, do this:

```
$("div[id^=intersection]").filter(function() {
    var header = this.id.substr(13); 
    var regex = new RegExp('_[a-zA-Z]+_\\d+_' + header + '$');
    return regex.test(this.id);
}).click();
```

It would be best if your `<div>` elements had a class in order to improve performance.

Something like:

```
$("div.intersection[id^=intersection]")...
```

Comment: This gets me sooo close, but can the word 'resources' be a wildcard string a-z, and can the '98' be the variable 'header'?

// code //



var header=$(this).attr('id').substr(13);
   
   $("div.bam_intersection[id^=intersection]").filter(function() {
       return /_resources_\d+_98/.test(this.id);
   }).click();

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With filter, and a proper regex, this should work

```
$("div:regex(id, ^intersection_\d_\d_5$)").each(function(){
    $(this).click();
});
```

### EDIT:

Try this regex instead `^intersection_[\w-[0-9]]+_\d+_\d+$`

You can replace parts between two underscores with the specific word/number if you know what it is.

Comment: I'm sorry, I told you the wrong match :'(

Here is what I want to hit:

id="intersection_A_B_C"

where A is some word, like 'resources', or 'content'
where B is some number, 1 - infinity
where C is some number, 1 - infinity, and is a javascript variable.

The id's are like:

id="intersection_resources_4_98"
id="intersection_content_7_98"
id="intersection_resources_8_123"

so if the javascript variable was 98, it'd hit the first two.

Sorry for the confusion :(

Comment: Here is my current function:

$(".bam_header_level").each(function(){
  
  $(this).click(function(){
   
   var header=$(this).attr('id').substr(13);
   
   $("div:regex(id, intersection_*_*_"+header+")").each(function(){
       $(this).click();
   });
   
  });
  
 });

Comment: @Josh, Wrote a new regex that follows the pattern `intersection_word_number_number`, just replace the part you need like you did in your example with a literal where applicable

Answer (score 0):

There is regex selector for jQuery:

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/

That is used like this:

$(':regex(id,^[aeiou])');

Comment: I'm aware of the selector, I just can't seem to make a match for my case :(

Comment: The wildcard character for regex is a single period. Do you mean something like this:

$("div:regex(id, intersection_._._5)")

Comment: If you want any integer, use this: [0-9]+

Answer (score 0):

Use [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method with custom function. Something like this:

```
var r = new RegExp("intersection_\d+_\d+_"+num);
$("div").filter(function(){
  return $(this).attr("id").match(r);
}).click();
```

Comment: I suck at regex, could you provide me one? Where the * and * can be any integer?

var num = 4;

"intersection_*_*_"+num